# sql linq lambda expression with .include .join and .where

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

New with Linq and Lambda, I'm struggling with this query:

```
var yarns = _context.YarnFullAdmins
            .Include(y => y.Brand)
            .Include(y => y.ColorProduct)
            .Join(_context.StockYarnResums,
              yarn => yarn.Id,
              sprodid => sprodid.YarnId,
              (yarn, sprodid) => new { yarn, sprodid })
            .Where(y => y.Id > 0);
```

Models

```
public class YarnFullAdmin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Int16 BrandId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public ColorProduct ColorProduct { get; set; }
    public int ColorProductId { get; set; }
}

public class StockYarnResum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public YarnFullAdmin YarnId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public short StockFront { get; set; }
    public short StockCorrection { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public short StockReal { get; set; }
}
```

.join gives me: CS0411 C# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: can you please provide sample model structure

Comment: Just added model samples. Thanks

Comment: Should be : sprodid.YarnId.Id

Comment: Thank you @jdweng. This works for .Join, but now, I have an error for .where statement: Error CS1061 “…Does Not Contain Definition and No Extension Method…accepting a first argument of type ” could be found

Comment: Should be : y => y.yarn.Id > 0  Even better move the where before the join.

Comment: Thanks. I did and it works. Ihave now a problem with:
            var viewModel = new YarnListViewModel
            {
                YarnList = yarns.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
                ....
            };